# AWS DynamoDB update item using multiple condition expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a DynamoDB Table and I want a particular value to be updated using multiple condition expression. Can we do that?
My code:-

```
        dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb')
        table = dynamodb.Table('gold-images')
        response = table.update_item(
            Key={
                    'AccountRegionOS' : AccOs,
                    'CreationDate' : cred
                },
            UpdateExpression="set is_active = :r",
            ConditionExpression="CreationDate < :num",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':num' : last_month,
                ':r': "No"
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
```

I want Condition expression to be

```
        dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb')
        table = dynamodb.Table('gold-images')
        response = table.update_item(
            Key={
                    'AccountRegionOS' : AccOs,
                    'CreationDate' : cred
                },
            UpdateExpression="set is_active = :r",
            ConditionExpression=("CreationDate < :num") & ("AMIID = :ami"),
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':num' : last_month,
                ':r': "No",
                ':ami' : i
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The condition expression is a string and the logical operators are `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`. So, you'll need to remove outer parentheses and replace `&` with `AND`:

```
ConditionExpression = "CreationDate < :num AND AMIID = :ami"
```

See [Condition Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using AWS lambda to update their DynamoDB table, here is an example:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const proxyResponseBody = ((statusCode, result) => {
  let response = {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify({ result: result }),
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
  }
  return response;
})

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  console.log(event);
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(event.body)
  const userId = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub
  const params = {
    TableName : "Some_Table_Name",
    Key: {
      "ID": jsonData.tableKeyId,
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set someField = :newValue",
    ConditionExpression: "userId = :userId",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":newValue": jsonData.newValue,
      ":userId": userId,
    },
  }
  console.log(params)
  let result = null
  let statusCode = null
  result = await documentClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      statusCode = 500
      return err
    }else {
      console.log(data);
      statusCode = 200
      return data
    }
  }).promise();
  return proxyResponseBody(statusCode, result)
};
```

The table consist of a partition key "ID", "userId", and a "fieldName". This function is to update the value of "fieldName" of a row which have the matching userId.